# ID Alfanumerico Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

buenas:

Estoy intentando generar ID's únicos con letras y números pero todos los métodos que he probado me devuelven strings que pueden dar la posibilidad de repetirse y hacen fallar la aplicación. Ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
class Comentario(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=9, default=token_generator.make_token(), editable=False)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, related_name='comentarios',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

y la siguiente clase que genera strings de forma aleatoria:

```
class RandomTokenGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, chars=None, random_generator=None):
        self.chars = chars or string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        self.random_generator = random_generator or random.SystemRandom()

    def make_token(self, n=9):
        return ''.join(self.random_generator.choice(self.chars) for _ in range(n))

token_generator = RandomTokenGenerator()
```

necesito que obligatoriamente sean 9 dígitos, por eso no me sirve el UUID que genera django

Comment: Para estar seguro que no hayan colisiones (IDs repetidos), creo que lo mejor sería generar esa secuencia del lado de la base de datos. El método debería pedirle a la base de datos un nuevo ID. La lógica de control de repeticiones la hace la base de datos y devuelve un valor único para esa tabla. El problema de hacer esto es que tenes que escribir algo de SQL crudo y aumenta el acoplamiento con ese motor de base de datos (ya no sería tan fácil migrar a otro motor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que uses  una funcion en vez de una clase para estet tipo de opciones

```
def random_id(lenght=9);
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for x in range(lenght))
```

y en tu modelo pasar el objeto funcion no la funcion en si

```
class Comentario(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=9, default=random_id, editable=False)
    perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil)
    comentario = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, related_name='comentarios',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

espero te sirva

Comment: si, mi problema era que le pasaba el objeto en si y no la función, muchas gracias

Comment: @FDelgado con el método que ejemplifica Ligorio, existe la posibilidad de que se repita un ID?

Comment: es muy complicado que salgan (en mi caso) 9 dígitos alfanumericos iguales. está pensado para una cantidad de digitos grande, cuantos menos digitos, más posibilidades de que te devuelva uno repetido porque limita la cantidad de posibilidades

Comment: @FDelgado si hay dos usuarios ingresando al mismo tiempo, se repite el numero ID?

Comment: No. La función random_id se ejecuta cada vez que se crea un nuevo comentario. No es necesario controlar ese tipo de cosas porque ya se encarga django de controlarlo.